# Reflect one client's message to another client on Websocket (golang)

Tags: go, websocket

I'm having a problem using websockets in my backend. I have to re-write some old with golang and old developer using websocket while one client tracking other client's location.

both client connecting websocket with given url

```
"\(URLConstants.webSocketURL)?token=\(token)&jobId=\(jobId)"
```

So I thought both client connecting websocket with her/his own token and I need to reflect user's message to other user. I can open two sockets with given url.

It's the first time that I'm using websocket so I'm not sure I'm asking the right question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the information to the existing sessions that you stored from opened connection and distribute the information to other users.

Try to go through this solution to get some inspiration https://github.com/suricatatalk/core/blob/master/core.go.

Comment: thank you man, I've couldn't find any example for this subject, it might help me but I have still some questions, can I ask you in private channel or anywhere else?

Comment: Reach me on twitter @radeksohlich.